# Trouble removing trailing newline from string

Tags: c, newline

I'm having trouble removing the trailing \n from a multiple line string then into tokens to list them for a table. The string is coming from a text file using input redirection (`< input.txt`). This is what I have so far:

The text file is:

```
Little Boy Blue, Come blow your horn, The sheep's in the meadow, The
cow's in the corn; Where is that boy Who looks after the sheep? Under
the haystack Fast asleep. Will you wake him? Oh no, not I, For if I do
He will surely cry.
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    char *line;
    char *ptr;
    char *pch;
    line = (char *) malloc(1);
    ptr = line;
    for (;( *line = c = tolower(getchar())) != EOF; line++);

    *line='\0';

    pch = strtok(ptr," \n,.-");
    while (pch != NULL) 
    {
        printf ("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ?;,.-");
    }
    return 0;      
}
```

Comment: Your code may raise SegmentationFault Exception at line 'for (;( *line=c = tolower(getchar()))!= EOF ;line++);', because your code allocates only 1 byte for char *line and many characters exists in your text file.  Is this your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have major memory allocation problems; you allocate one byte of memory, and then try to read a large number of characters into it, and add an null byte at the end.  You need to fix that.

Your code is also a little puzzling in that the delimiters change between the two calls to `strtok()`.  That's allowed, but it isn't clear why you don't include newline in the second and question mark and semicolon in the first (and what about exclamation mark and colon?).

Note that `tolower()` is declared in `<ctype.h>`.

The simplest way to eliminate the newline at the end is to overwrite it with the null byte.  If you need to map other newlines as well, do the translation as the data is read.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    char *line = (char *)malloc(1);
    size_t l_max = 1;
    char *ptr = line;

    if (line == 0)
        return 1;  // Report out of memory?

    while ((c = tolower(getchar())) != EOF)
    {
        if (ptr == line + l_max - 1)
        {
            char *extra = realloc(line, 2 * l_max);
            if (extra == 0)
                return 1;  // Report out of memory?
            l_max *= 2;
            line = extra;
        }
        *ptr++ = c;
    }

    if (*(ptr - 1) == '\n')
        ptr--;
    *ptr = '\0';

    static const char markers[] = " \n\t,.;:?!-";
    char *pch = strtok(line, markers);

    while (pch != NULL) 
    {
        printf ("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, markers);
    }
    return 0;      
}
```

You could also just leave the newline in the data; `strtok()` will end up skipping over it.